# Create excel file using PHP compatible for 2007 and 2003

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007

am creating a  .xls file using PHP  fopen

write and append  the contents to the file. Works fine with Excel 2003.

But excel 2007 showing a alert before opening as un supported type.

If i create file with  .xlsx extension , it is not opening in 2003.

Is there any standard way that works fine in both 2003 and 2007 versions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What format are you actually writing? Writing an Excel file isn't simply a matter of giving an arbitrary file an extension of xlsx or xls.

For commonality, you can write a BIFF5 or BIFF8 xls file (all versions of Excel post 95 will read this), or there is the Excel 2003 XML format, which can be opened by both Excel 2003 and Excel2007 (and Excel 2010 as well).

Comment: am creating a .xls file, write the contents to the file as \t  tab seperated.

Comment: @zod - No, you're not creating an xls file, you're creating a tab-delimited file... don't give it an xls extension: Excel 2007 is basically telling you that you're lying to it, that what you're claiming is an xls file is no such thing. Try writing as comma-separated value rather than tab-separated, and giving it an extension of .csv (Excel should open this without issue), or create a real xls BIFF5 or BIFF8 file.

Comment: yea . that is the only way i have now.

Comment: @zod - Creating a CSV file is easier if you don't need formatting or multiple worksheets, or any of the other special features of Excel: if you do need any of those extras, then there is still the option of creating a real MS Excel file using one of the available PHP libraries for Excel

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It's free and can read/write Excel 03/07 files directly. There's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer in the PEAR library, but it's essentially dead and only support writing BIFF5 files, which corresponds to Excel '95 ('97? not sure...)

Comment: For future reference, BIFF5 is Excel5/95, BIFF8 is Excel97/2003

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any formatting or even multiple sheets the easiest thing to do is to just create a comma-separated file. (.csv) 2003 and 2007 can open those just fine. It's also much easier to deal with in PHP

Comment: not what he asked for, but right! As long as you don't need to generate complex XLS Files (including different sheets and other meta stuff) CSV is the way to go, still, I guess that would had made more sense as a comment

Comment: actually am writing tab seperated files to .xls files. This is not pure xls i know. Then how can i write content to a pure xls file?

Comment: Just saving it as .XLS doesn't make it .XLS  ... I'm surprised it works at all. If you change the extension to .csv (even with tab separated) it should import in 2007

Answer (score 0):

I bet he wants to to the same thing I want: create a tab-delimited file (instead of comma-delimited), to avoid dealing with apostrophes or commas with the cells. Just $field_contents . "\t" . $next_field_contents

We know that if we create a comma-delimited file with extension CSV the browser will send it to Excel (somehow). What I want (and the questioner probably wants) is a way to:

1. produce a TAB-delimited file
2. have the browser tell the operating system to have Excel open it
3. (but not ask the user any questions, e.g., about formatting)

Those who do not know how to do this, please shush! But if anyone knows whether this is possible or not, please speak up!!!!